# Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type 'DbSet<>'. Ambiguous call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, .net

```
public List<ClassParticipantViewModel> GetClassParticipants(string studentId)
{
    List<ClassParticipantViewModel> list = new List<ClassParticipantViewModel>();

    var results = (from cp in _DbContext.ClassParticipants
                   join c in _DbContext.Classes
                   on cp.ClassId equals c.ClassId
                   where cp.StudentId.Equals(studentId)
                   select new ClassParticipantViewModel
                   {
                       //ClassParticipant
                       ClassParticipantId = cp.ClassParticipantId,
                       StudentId = cp.StudentId,
                       ClassParticipantCreatedOn = cp.CreatedOn,

                       //Class
                       ClassId = c.ClassId,
                       ClassCode = c.ClassCode,
                       Section = c.Section,
                       CourseCode = c.CourseCode,
                       Description = c.Description,
                       Units = c.Units,
                       CreatedBy = c.CreatedBy,
                       ClassCreatedOn = c.CreatedOn,
                   })
                   .ToList();

    list = list.Concat(results).ToList();

    return list.ToList();
}
```

Join error:

[image]

Models:

[image]

ViewModel:

[image]

I'm developing a Web API using .NET Core 3.0 then I got an error stating that Ambiguous call to 'Join', this code is worked in my other projects. I'm confused if what is wrong, does the naming convention of my models have an effect?

Comment: Judging by the names of your entities, I'd expect there to be navigation properties between them, which would mean this manual join creation would be unnecessary.. Why doesn't a Class have e.g. `ICollection<ClassParticipant> ClassParticipants {get;set;}` and a ClassParticiant have a `Class Class{get;set;}` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard How can I join the two if join creation is unnecessary? I need the details of Class based on the StudentId.

Comment: The initialization of `list` in the first line of the method is redundant.

Comment: @TsahiAsher Thanks, adjusted but still getting the error Ambiguous call to 'Join'.

Comment: When you've told EF how two objects relate (e.g. by having a collection of ClassParticipants in a Class, or by having a Class in a ClassParticipant) you can just say `context.Classes.Include(c =>c.ClassParticipants)` to load all the classes and their related classparticipants. If you use the linkage in a where or select clause it also auto joins

Comment: it worked @CaiusJard. Thank you!
 `var testResults = _DbContext.ClassParticipants.Include(s => s.Classes).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.StudentId == studentId);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick intro to navigation props in EF:

If your classes looked like:

```
class Class {
  ICollection<ClassParticipant> ClassParticipants {get; set;}
  ...
}
class ClassParticipant {
  Class Class{get;set;}
  Participant Participant{get;set;}
  ...
}
class Participant{
  ICollection<ClassParticipant> ParticipantClasses {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

EF would be able to work out that this is a typical 1:M:1 relationship between classes:classparticipants:participants - many classes have many participants and the middle table breaks it down.

Once you've done that property mapping, you can write queries like:

```
_DbContext.ClassParticipants.Select(cp =>
   new ClassParticipantViewModel
   {
       //ClassParticipant
       ClassParticipantId = cp.ClassParticipantId,
       StudentId = cp.StudentId,
       ClassParticipantCreatedOn = cp.CreatedOn,

       //Class
       ClassId = cp.Class.ClassId,
       ClassCode = cp.Class.ClassCode,
       Section = cp.Class.Section,
       CourseCode = cp.Class.CourseCode,
       Description = cp.Class.Description,
       Units = cp.Class.Units,
       CreatedBy = cp.Class.CreatedBy,
       ClassCreatedOn = cp.Class.CreatedOn,
   }
).ToList();
```

EF will see you navigating around in the select (`cp.Class.ClassId`), and know it has to join Classes in to get the data you want. You can also make direct navigational references in a similar way in a `Where` clause to load the related data, or, if you know you won't refer to the related data in the `Select` or `Where`, but you will want the data to be loaded so you can later refer to it in C#, you can use Include:

```
_DbContext.ClassParticipants.Include(cp => cp.Class).ToList();
```

footnote, you might want to have e.g. `ICollection<ClassParticipant> ClassParticipants {get; set;} = new HashSet<ClassParticipant>();` because it makes creating new entities easier, not having to remember to make the collection first:

```
var c = new Class(...);
var p = new Participant(...);

//can do this without having to remember to make a new collection
c.ClassParticipants.Add(new ClassParticipant { Class = c, Participant = p });
```

Comment: In my EF6 experience, I would strongly recommend creating a temporary reference to `Class`, e.g. `let c = cp.Class` in the LINQ query, and then use `c.ClassId` etc., otherwise every call to `cp.Class....` will add a `JOIN` statement to the generated SQL, killing your performance. I don't know how to do that in method call syntax.

Comment: @TsahiAsher tested this assertion just now on EFCore 5, and didn't see any indication that it was the case now; for my tests a single JOIN is created and reused

Comment: Then maybe they improved it in EFCore.